# Can I have sudoedit check `$EDITOR` like visudo does?

Tags: linux, sudo, text-editors, sudoers

As far as I know, the major difference is that visudo has a simple parser for seeing if /etc/sudoers (and other sudoers files) is goodly; however, I also noticed that, when I set `EDITOR=emacs`, sudoedit honors the change, however, visudo does not.  From what I can tell, this is because Visudo does not honor `$EDITOR` values unless they are listed in sudoers.
What I want to know is if I can make sudoedit do the same thing, to not allow things like `EDITOR=deleverything.sh`.

Another thing I noticed, which seems related, is that as root (after su-ing as user jef), (with the line `export EDITOR=emacs` in /home/anachrome/.bashrc), both visudo and sudoedit use emacs as the editor, but when not su'd into root, only sudoedit uses it.  I'm curious as to why this is (I presume it has something to do with sudo not resetting the environment variables when sudoing as yourself (e.g. `root $ sudo -u root`), but this is just me assuming).

EDIT: The second question is just because `$EDITOR` wasn't one of the variables kept by sudo.

And incidentally, I'm using Arch Linux, in case that's relevant.

Comment: Wouldn't `sudo env` answer the second part of your question?

Comment: Ah.  A quick check confirms that if I run something with 'sudo' EDITOR isn't used, while if I run something without, (i.e., I'm root and don't need sudo), EDITOR is preserved.  Thanks for that.

Comment: You can configure which environment variables are considered safe in /etc/sudoers. All others are usually unset by sudo.

Comment: Yea, I figured that out now, my real question is: visudo, when determining which editor to use, only considers $EDITOR if it is in the list defined by `Defaults editor=[...]`.  How can I make sudoedit mirror this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

For me on Arch, neither `visudo` nor `sudoedit` honor `$EDITOR` but they **do** both honor `$VISUAL`, so maybe that's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Also check that the desired editor is actually installed.  Specifying `EDITOR=vim` when all you've got is `vi.tiny` won't give much joy.